# Suitescript 2.0 - how to get a particular product SKU within a Sales Order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm working on a script which required to find a particular product SKU within a Sales Order.

Order is placed through webservice API and every time an order is placed, I need to search for a particular product.

I did look at the Suitescript 2.0 API documentation and its seems there are a two options for me to investigate: 1 - Line item, 2 - Sublist

I'm wondering if anyone can give me a hint on how to achieve this on suitescript 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to find a line in SS2.0.

```
// Finding a specific line item in SuiteScript 2.0...
require(["N/record"], function (r) {
    var rec = r.load({
        "type": r.Type.SALES_ORDER,
        "id": 123
    });

    // Find the line that contains item 777
    var index = rec.findSublistLineWithValue({"sublistId": "item", "fieldId": "item", "value": 777});

    // find returns -1 if the item isn't found
    if (index > -1) {
        // we found it on line "index"
    } else {
        // item 777 is not in the list
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much @Adolfo Garza